# Cats-tagless - Scala macro annotation error

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-cats, scala-macro-paradise

I have created a simple `trait` using `cats-tagless` lib:

```
@finalAlg
@autoFunctorK(true)
trait MyService[F[_]] {

  def put(element: Element): F[Element]

  def get(elementId: Id): F[Element]

  def all(): F[List[Element]]

  def delete(elementId: Id): F[Unit]
}
```

but when I tried to compile it, I got an error:

```
Error:(8, 7) macro annotation could not be expanded (the most common reason for that is that you need to enable the macro paradise plugin; another possibility is that you try to use macro annotation in the same compilation run that defines it)
```

I also added `addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1" cross CrossVersion.full)` into `plugins.sbt` file and `build.sbt` but it did not help. Can you help me to solve it?

My `build.sbt` file looks like:

```
addCompilerPlugin(("org.scalameta" % "paradise" % "3.0.0-M11").cross(CrossVersion.full))

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % CatsVersion,
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % "1.2.0",
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats-tagless-macros" % "0.5",
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats-tagless-legacy-macros" % "0.5",
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats-mtl-core" % "0.5.0",
  )
)
```

Comment: What is `CatsVersion`?

Comment: currently 1.6.0

Comment: Yes, I'm using it in module `algebra` where I have created service `trait`. Use it like this `lazy val algebra = (project in file("algebra"))
  .settings(commonSettings)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an empty new project with this `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-tagless-macros" % "0.5",
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-tagless-legacy-macros" % "0.5"
)

addCompilerPlugin(
  "org.scalameta" % "paradise" % "3.0.0-M11" cross CrossVersion.full
)
```

this code:

```
import cats.tagless._

case class Element()
case class Id()

@finalAlg
@autoFunctorK(true)
trait MyService[F[_]] {
  def put(element: Element): F[Element]
  def get(elementId: Id): F[Element]
  def all(): F[List[Element]]
  def delete(elementId: Id): F[Unit]
}
```

compiles just fine, as advertised [here](https://typelevel.org/cats-tagless/).

If I remove `addCompilerPlugin("org.scalameta" % "paradise" % "3.0.0-M11" cross  CrossVersion.full)`, I get the same error message:

> macro annotation could not be expanded (the most common reason for that is that you need to enable the macro paradise plugin; another possibility is that you try to use macro annotation in the same compilation run that defines it)

Again, this is as documented, the linked page says:

> The macro annotations (@finalAlg, `@autoFunctorK`, @autoInvariantK, etc.) still depends on scalameta, so you need to add scalameta dependencies in build.sbt.

So it seems that you need it because of `@finalAlg` and `@autoFunctorK`.

Note that I didn't modify anything in `project/`.

---

**EDIT**

If you have multiple subprojects, you have to add the compiler plugin to the subproject that actually needs it. Notice that

```
addCompilerPlugin(foobar)
```

is essentially just

```
libraryDependencies += compilerPlugin(foobar)
```

so in your case, you probably should try something like

```
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.6.0",
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % "1.2.0",
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats-tagless-macros" % "0.5",
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats-tagless-legacy-macros" % "0.5",
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats-mtl-core" % "0.5.0",
    compilerPlugin(("org.scalameta" % "paradise" % "3.0.0-M11")
      .cross(CrossVersion.full))
  )
```

and then add this to your `algebra` subproject.

Comment: I added `addCompilerPlugin(
  ("org.scalameta" % "paradise" % "3.0.0-M11").cross(CrossVersion.full))` and  `"org.typelevel" %% "cats-tagless-macros" % latestVersion` and `"org.typelevel" %% "cats-tagless-legacy-macros" % latestVersion` to `build.sbt` and it did not help

Comment: @allocer In what sense did it not help? There are thousand things that could have gone wrong, it's impossible to find out without a proper MCVE.

Comment: @allocer I produced an example that reproduces the error, then I've shown a `build.sbt` that avoids the error. If you have some other example that doesn't work, then you'd have to show it.

Comment: @allocer My last guess so far: take a look at the edit, please. I'm guessing that you somehow added the plugin to the wrong subproject.

Comment: great, it helped to move `compilerPlugin(("org.scalameta" % "paradise" % "3.0.0-M11")(CrossVersion.full))` into commonSettings. Thanks